# How to create custom button with shape using clip path widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create custom button with shape using clip path widget in flutter along with the curves / arcs at two opposite corners.[see the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGkdt.png)

Comment: every button has `shape` property - just use it instead of "clip path" widget

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html I got only this

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton/shape.html use it for example in [RaisedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton/RaisedButton.html) constructor

Comment: thanks for your response. See the attached image I can't achieve same thing using shape. help me to draw that arc @top-right and bottom-left corner on button or simple container. 

Comment: You might need to use stack widget to get the effects on top right and bottom left arcs. Use Stack, add ClipPath and the arcs.